# removing multiple ace editors within tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, ace-editor

I'm ultimately making an IDE using nw.js so the contents and filenames will be coming from the person's PC but this fiddle replicates the information I'll have. If you open a tab and then close it with the 'x' button and check your console you'll see it fails with finding the editor element, but if you dig in the DOM you'll see it's there. Any idea why removing the tab blows up? I'm trying to figure out how to clean things up when the user wants to close a file.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lu35rqm/

```
$.fn.addEditorTab = function (name, tabName, contents) {
    $('ul', this).append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + tabName + '</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation"></li>');
    $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'><div id='editor-" + name + "' class='editor'></div></div>");
    $(this).tabs("refresh");

    var editor = ace.edit("editor-" + name);
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor.getSession().setValue(contents);

    return editor;
};

$(function(){
    var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
  var editors = {};

  var file1Path = "D:/Test/file1.js";
  var file1Name = "file1.js";
  var file1Contents = "function foo(items) { \r var x = \"All this is syntax highlighted\";\r   return x;\r}";

  var file2Path = "D:/Test/file2.js";
  var file2Name = "file2.js";
    var file2Contents = "function bar(items) { \r   var x = \"All this is syntax highlighted\";\r   return x;\r}";

  editors[file1Path] = tabs.addEditorTab(file1Path, file1Name, file1Contents);
  editors[file2Path] = tabs.addEditorTab(file2Path, file2Name, file2Contents);

  tabs.on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
      var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
      var editorId = panelId.replace("tab-", "editor-");

      console.log("A");
      $("#" + editorId).remove();

      console.log("B");
      $("#" + panelId).remove();

      console.log("C");
      editors[editorId.replace("-editor", "")].destroy();

      console.log("D");
      tabs.tabs("refresh");
    });
});
```

Comment: Man, added the close code and a fiddle and get downvoted. Sometimes I just don't get it.

Comment: When I review the fiddle, I see you have jQuery 2.0.2 loaded and externally call jQuery 3.2.1. I also see a number of errors in the console. Would fix your fiddle first.

Comment: Also, `editors[editorId.replace("-editor", "")].destroy();` will fail to replace anything. Since `editorId` should be `editor-D:/Test/file1.js` at this point. The string `-editor` will not exist. Hence the index will not exist.

Comment: Further testing, I see Error: `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #editor-D:/Test/file1.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the selectors: `$("#tab-D:/Test/file1.js")` & `$("#editor-D:/Test/file1.js")`. Switching them to a different selector helped.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`. The W3C CSS specification contains the complete set of [rules regarding valid CSS selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on [CSS character escape sequences for identifiers](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pp5ssbLn/

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.addEditorTab = function(name, tabName, contents) {
  $('ul', this).append('<li><a href="#tab-' + name + '">' + tabName + '</a><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close" role="presentation"></li>');
  $(this).append("<div id='tab-" + name + "'><div id='editor-" + name + "' class='editor'></div></div>");
  $(this).tabs("refresh");

  var editor = ace.edit("editor-" + name);
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
  editor.getSession().setValue(contents);

  return editor;
};

$(function() {
  var tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
  var editors = {};

  var file1Path = "D:/Test/file1.js";
  var file1Name = "file1.js";
  var file1Contents = "function foo(items) { \r var x = \"All this is syntax highlighted\";\r   return x;\r}";

  var file2Path = "D:/Test/file2.js";
  var file2Name = "file2.js";
  var file2Contents = "function bar(items) { \r var x = \"All this is syntax highlighted\";\r   return x;\r}";

  editors[file1Path] = tabs.addEditorTab(file1Path, file1Name, file1Contents);
  editors[file2Path] = tabs.addEditorTab(file2Path, file2Name, file2Contents);

  tabs.on("click", "span.ui-icon-close", function() {
    var panelId = $(this).closest("li").remove().attr("aria-controls");
    var editorId = panelId.replace("tab-", "editor-");

    console.log("A, Editor: " + editorId);
    $("div[id='" + editorId + "']").remove();

    console.log("B, Panel: " + panelId);
    $("div[id='" + panelId + "']").remove();

    console.log("C");
    editors[editorId.replace("editor-", "")].destroy();

    console.log("D");
    tabs.tabs("refresh");
  });
});
```

Also applied fix for `editors[editorId.replace("-editor", "")].destroy();`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Any idea what's up with the selectors not working when done indirectly vs specifying div[id=]? This works and thank you btw. So it doesn't have to be escaped if used like div[id=]?

Comment: Updated. The file name is just complex. I tried testing by adding the escaping, so that it use `var file1Path = "D\\:\\/Test\\/file1\\.js";`, yet this didn't translate when being used as the selector. The use of the single quote inside seems to help escape or match better. Personally, I would use a much less complex ID, like `file-1`, and store the Path and Name as  `data` attributes maybe.

Comment: @user441521 this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/pp5ssbLn/3/ store all your file details in a object and create IDs that are easier to manage.

Comment: Thanks for helping. This was a test, in my real nw.js app they are launching a file by dbl clicking a representation of a file on disk on a tree view. I don't need to store those in any kind of container but thanks for sharing. I just have to find a good layout now for all of this.

Comment: @user441521 I suspected that might be the case, so that was why I wanted to share the improved fiddle.